# Is this model overfit or underfit?

Tags: validation, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, face-recognition, overfitting-underfitting

I am working on a face authentication project. While the model performs well on the training data, it struggles with unseen data. When I plot the graph comparing the training accuracy with the model accuracy, I observe this trend

[image: model_accuracy]

model loss:

[image: model_loss]

CNN model:

```
model = Sequential()
        model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(int(self.org_img_height),int(self.org_img_width),3)))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
        model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
        model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
        model.add(Flatten())
        model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dropout(0.5))
        model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

Answer (score 1):

What makes you think that this model is either Overfit  or Underfit?
From the first graph, your training accuracy is increasing with each epoch and so is your validation accuracy. Similarly, from the second graph, your training loss is decreasing and so is your validation loss. So this means your training is on the right track. Neither Overfit not underfit.

You will reach the overfit condition wen your training loss is low and your validation loss is high. This is not the case here.
Similarly, your will have underfitting if your training loss and validation losses both are high and this is also not the case here. As depicted in the figure below.

[image]

Comment: but model not working properly on unseen data

Comment: There can be a lot of reasons for that. If I had the same issue I would try a couple of things such as; 1. You can  improve your train and validation dataset split ratio i.e. add more data to validation set. 2. Use the Adam Optimizer, it works better. 3. If you can increase the size of the dataset by gathering more data and by dataset augmentation.

Comment: Yes, I used data augmentation to increase my dataset from 200 to 600 images, and I opted for the Adam optimizer and binary cross entropy as loss function . I cropped the background of the images using Haarcascade classifier.